# Save GIF Image in Photo Gallery from UIImageView

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage, gif

I have UIImageView which is displaying GIF image, now I am unable to save GIF image into photo gallery.

I am using below swift code

```
guard let image = imageView.image else { return }

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
self, 
#selector(savedImage), 
nil);
```

When I use above code it only save single image in photo gallery not saving as GIF.

Suggestion required, how to save GIF loaded from URL or available in the UIImageView into Gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First your need to get all images of gif from imageView and the duration of the image, now you can generate the gif and save in document directory. Finally, save the file from URL to Photo Album**

```
 import ImageIO
 import Photos
 import MobileCoreServices

@IBAction func btnSaveGifFilePressed(_ sender: Any) {
    
    if let imgs = self.imgView.image?.images, imgs.count > 0 {
        var animationDuration = self.imgView.image?.duration ?? 1.0
        animationDuration = animationDuration / Double(imgs.count);
        
        let url = FileManager.default.urlForFile("lion.gif")
        FileManager.default.createGIF(with: imgs, url: url, frameDelay: animationDuration)
        
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges ({
            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(atFileURL: url)
        }) { saved, error in
            if saved {
                print("Your image was successfully saved")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Create GIF using the following code.**

```
func createGIF(with images: [UIImage], url: URL, frameDelay: Double) {

    if let destinationGIF = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, kUTTypeGIF, images.count, nil) {
        let properties = [
            (kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String): [(kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime as String): frameDelay]
        ]
        
        for img in images {
            let cgImage = img.cgImage
            CGImageDestinationAddImage(destinationGIF, cgImage!, properties as CFDictionary?)
        }
        CGImageDestinationFinalize(destinationGIF)
    }
}
```

**Get a URL in single line:**

```
func urlForFile(_ fileName: String, folderName: String? = nil) -> URL {
  
    var documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    
    if let folder = folderName {
        documentsDirectory = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(folder)
        if !self.fileExists(atPath: documentsDirectory.path) {
            try? self.createDirectory(atPath: documentsDirectory.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        }
    }
    
    let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    return fileURL;
}
```

Comment: I was able to compile and perform the task after import ImageIO
import Photos
import MobileCoreServices